# Java StringTokenizer for special character

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I want dont tokenize between special character like " ", { }, [ ] how can i do ?

```
String: "192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] 'GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0' 200 3395"
```

i want this output  :

```
192.168.2.20 
28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300
GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0
200 3395
```

My code:

```
String rawData= "192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] 'GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0' 200 3395";
int i=0;
String[] s1=new String[100];
String delim = " ";
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(rawData, delim, true);

boolean expectDelim = false;
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String token = tok.nextToken();
    if (delim.equals(token)) {
        if (expectDelim) {
            expectDelim = false;
            continue;
        } else {
            token = null;
        }
    }
    s1[i]=token;
    System.out.println(s1[i]);
    i+=1;
    expectDelim = true;
    }
}
```

output:

```
192.168.2.20
-
-
[28/Jul/2006:10:27:10
-0300]
'GET
/cgi-bin/try/
HTTP/1.0'
200
3395
```

i can do this for this log. But i want to use my code for all apache log. How can i do this ?

Comment: Does passing multiple delimiters to the StringTokenizer constructor solve your problem? `new StringTokenizer(rawData, " -[]''");`

Comment: No I don't think so. For that problem you can use string tokenizer or simply split method on string and create function that parse one line and run it in loop.

Comment: From the [Javadoc for `StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) - _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code_. Use `String.split()` and regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s.*\\s.*\\s\\[(.*)\\]\\s\\'(.*)\\'\\s(.*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] 'GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0' 200 3395");
        boolean b = m.matches();

        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
        System.out.println(m.group(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: İ want use this tokenizer for all log, this regex for only apache access log.

Answer (score 0):

Check out following code. Include the special characters that you don't want while tokenizing in the "delim" string of following code snippet.

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
String delim = "!,?._'@ ";
StringTokenizer st  = new StringTokenizer(s, delim);
System.out.println(st.countTokens());
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```